# Xamarin NSPredicate not working for PHAsset.FetchAssets

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When using the predicate the result is that no photos are returned. If I remove the predicate from the options then all my photos are returned as normal. Here is the code I am attempting:

```
PHFetchOptions options = new PHFetchOptions();
NSSortDescriptor[] sortDescriptors = new NSSortDescriptor[1];
sortDescriptors[0] = new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", false);
options.SortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

// So far I've tried the following predicates: 
///// 
options.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("mediaSubtype != " + PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoLive);
options.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("mediaSubtype == " + PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoLive);
options.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("mediaSubtype & " + PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoLive);
options.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("NOT ((mediaSubtype & " + PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoLive + ") != 0");
options.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("mediaSubtype = " + PHAssetMediaSubtype.None);
options.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("mediaSubtype == " + PHAssetMediaSubtype.None);
/////
return PHAsset.FetchAssets(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bitwise operators:

```
NSPredicate.FromFormat(string.Format("((mediaSubtype & {0}) == {0})", (int)PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoLive));
```

#### Example of getting photo assets of HDR subtype:

```
var options = new PHFetchOptions();
options.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat(string.Format("((mediaSubtype & {0}) == {0})", (int)PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoHDR)); 
var fetchResults = PHAsset.FetchAssets(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options);
foreach (var item in fetchResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine((item as PHAsset).MediaSubtypes);
}
```

Comment: Hello @SushiHangover.. I am trying to do the same thing for `mediaType` with value `PHAssetMediaType.Image` but I am getting error saying invalid predicate value. Can you explain how bitwise operators work for defining mediatype ?

Comment: @Monica Post a new question on what you are trying to do, that way the community (and I) can help.

Comment: @Monica Use PHAsset.FetchAssets(PHAssetMediaType.Image, fetchOptions) methods instead.